# How can I check if the selected account has my custom token?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I'm working on the project that interacts with metamask. I have 2 custom tokens which I have to add to the selected account's wallet if they are missing. To achieve it I'm using a method called `wallet_watchAsset`. The problem is that I don't know how to detect if a selected account has my custom tokens in order to add them. So, every time when I'm reloading the page with the app I see metamask window that asks me if I would like to add custom tokens, even if I already have them in the wallet.

How can I get list of connected tokens in the selected account or how can I detect if the selected account has my tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ERC-20 balance of the connected MetaMask address before putting it on the watch list. Only put addresses on the watch list that have balance on them.

Comment: that doesn't work. An account having non zero balance of a given custom token doesn't mean it has this asset added to the wallet